# Restricting Parent Issue status based on sub-task status in JIRA

Tags: conditional-statements, workflow, scriptrunner-for-jira

I want to Restrict Parent Issue status transition based on one sub-task status. I see I can add script runner. WHat will be my script?

Unable to get the result by using the script runner.

Comment: Please also mention what you have tried and done so far.